# Why do Child CSS Elements inherit from > Selector unless an explicit behavior is specified?

Tags: html, css, inheritance

Given the following:

```css
.site-map > li {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<ul class="site-map">
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>I expect this to be black (default color) 1</li>
      <li>I expect this to be black (default color)</li>
    </ul>
  <li>First Level Red</li>
</ul>
```

...What seems to happen is that the  child `li` are still red UNLESS I make the following adjustment:

```css
.site-map li { color: #000; }
.site-map > li { color: #f00; }
```

```html
<ul class="site-map">
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>I expect this to be black (default color) 1</li>
      <li>I expect this to be black (default color)</li>
    </ul>
  <li>First Level Red</li>
</ul>
```

So it appears that unless one -explicitly- specifies a default for the children, then those children -still- inherit the style from `.sitemap > li`.

Do I have this correct? I'm confused as to why this should be the case.

Can someone please explain the logic behind this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default value for the `color` property (for most elements) is [`inherit`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#value-def-inherit), which means "Copy the computed value from the parent element".

The outer `li` has `color: red`.

The child `ul` has `color: inherit` so gets `red` as the computed value.

The child `li` also has `color: inherit` so gets `red` as the computed value.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [W3 Documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/colors.html#propdef-color), the color property has this:

> Value:     <.color.> | inherit 
>   Initial:    depends on user agent
>   Applies to:     all elements
>   Inherited:      yes
>   Percentages:    N/A
>   Media:      visual
>   Computed value:     as specified

Then we can know by the first two lines, if the element hasn't an initial value defined by the user agent ("browser default stylesheet") will inherit the color from the parent element.

---

An example with initial value defined by the user agent will be the `a` tag, this has from the user agent:

```
a:-webkit-any-link {
    color: -webkit-link;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: auto;
}
```

Then don't take the parent's color.

```css
.site-map > li {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<ul class="site-map">
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">I expect this to be black (default color) 1</a></li>
      <li>I expect this to be black (default color)</li>
    </ul>
  <li>First Level Red</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks. This also might clear up another confusion I've had as to why the color on a tags doesn't seem to operate like other elements.

Comment: glad to help U understand @jchwebdev

Comment: Although I don't really understand the logic... eg. why the 'a' tag doesn't inherit color but li does. Seems a bit arbitrary.

Comment: because the `a` tag has an initial value for the color by the user agent the li doesn't have that initial style from the user agent therefore inherits the parent color @jchwebdev